# Is there limitation for recursion?

Tags: c++

I am testing recursion, however when I have an array with more than 150000 elements  segmentation error occurs. What can be the problem?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void init ( float a[] , long int n );

float standard ( float a[] , long int n , long int i );

int main()
{
    long int n = 1000000;

    float *a = new float[n];

    init ( a , n );
    cout.precision ( 30 );
    cout << "I got here." << endl;

    cout << "Standard sum= " << standard ( a , 0 , n - 1 ) << endl;

    delete [] a;
    return 0;

}

void init ( float a[] , long int n )
{

    for (long int  i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ )
    {
        a[i] = 1. / ( i + 1. );
    }
}

float standard ( float a[] , long int i , long int n )
{
    if ( i <= n )
        return a[i] + standard ( a , i + 1 , n );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it does, it is a pointer what I am passing there.

Comment: I have misread, sorry

Comment: I think you mean "recursion" rather than "backtracking".

Comment: In any case, trhat smells more of stack overflow instead of segmentation fault.

Comment: I am getting the following result: `I got here.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Comment: @deviantfan a stack overflow *is* a segmentation fault, is it not?

Comment: @user2079303 ...but usually reported differently, I don´t quite get my own computer now (or I remember my last SO not well)

Comment: @deviantfan stack overflow has undefined behaviour so reporting (if there is any) is implementation defined. A SIGSEGV signal is quite typical result on linux in my experience.

Comment: @user2079303 `implementation defined.` Yes, nobody said something else.

Comment: @deviantfan, sorry, I didn't make my point clear. I meant to imply that since the behaviour is implementation defined, perhaps your different experience with it's *reporting* is from an implementation other than what OP is using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an expansion to MicroVirus' correct answer, here is an example of tail recursive version of your algorithm:

```
float standard_recursion(float* a, long i, long n, long result) {
    if(i > n)
        return result;
    return standard_recursion(a, i + 1, n, result + a[i]);
}

float standard(float* a, long i, long n ) {
    return standard_recursion(a, i, n, 0);
}
```

This should run if the compiler does tail call optimization (I tested on g++ -O2). However, since the functionality depends on the compiler optimization, I would recommend to avoid deep recursion entirely and opt for iterative solution.

Answer (score 2):

You are most likely running out of stack space in your recursive function `standard`, which recurses with a depth of `n`, and tail-call optimisation is probably not enabled here.

So, to answer the question in your title: Yes, there is a limit to recursion, and usually it's the available stack space.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are out of memory on heap. Also if you got 16bit int, there could be a problem with iterations. Better use int32_t i instead of int i. Same with n.

Comment: I doubt he's running out of heap space. 150000 floats is about half a megabyte.

Comment: No reason to use use explicit-bitsize types here (i.e. the `int32_t`): stick to int, or else go for long, unless the width of the type needs to be fixed to some exact number.

Comment: @user2079303: It wouldn't be 150000 floats. It would be 150000 stack frames - the sum of all local variables + the return pointer

Comment: OK. I see now. This answer is a partial answer that should be read with MicroVirus's answer.

Comment: @LokiAstari yes, those stack frames probably consume more memory. Possibly not enough to fill the heap though. But as the name implies, stack frames are stored on the stack and that's where he's run out of memory - not on the heap. Maximum stack size does not grow according to use, it's limit is set on compilation.